# Is there any way to know which ssh key I'm using right now?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have created 2 ssh key on my github but i don't know which key i'm using right now.

I have tried using `ssh -T git@github.com` but noting happens. I'm new in programming and learning git and github so I don't know much about this.

Comment: Add `-v`  or `-vv` to `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the default paths, see the `id_rsa.pub`, `id_ecdsa.pub`, `id_ecdsa_sk.pub`, `id_ed25519.pub`, `id_ed25519_sk.pub` or `id_dsa.pub` file on your PC in `~/.ssh/`. Compare them to the github key.

Comment: What if there're a few keypairs — how to know which one SSH is using right now?

Comment: By default, SSH will only look at some places by default: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#i

The `-V` switch was also mentioned in a comment above, this should  work if there are multiple possible keys.